# Using boost::mutex as a private member of class

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread, boost-mutex

I have a class that contains a boost::mutex as a private member. It becomes locked when you call one of its public functions and unlocks when the function exits. This is to provide synchronous access to the object's internals.

```
class StringDeque
{
  boost::mutex mtx;
  std::deque<string> string_deque;
public:
  StringDeque() { }

  void addToDeque(const string& str_to_add)
  {
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> guard(mtx);
    string_deque.push(str_to_add);
  }

  string popFromDeque()
  {
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> guard(mtx);
    string popped_string = string_deque.front();
    string_deque.pop();
    return popped_string;
  }
};
```

This class isn't meant to be particularly useful but I am just playing around with mutexes and threads.

I have a main() that also has another function defined that pops strings from the class and prints them in a thread. It will repeat this 10 times and then return from the function. Once again, this is purely for testing purposes. It looks like this:

```
void printTheStrings(StringDeque& str_deque)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 10)
    {
      string popped_string = str_deque.popFromDeque();
      if(popped_string.empty())
      {
        sleep(1);
        continue;
      }
      cout << popped_string << endl;
      ++i;
    }
}

int main()
{
  StringDeque str_deque;
  boost::thread the_thread(printTheStrings, str_deque);
  str_deque.addToDeque("Say your prayers");
  str_deque.addToDeque("Little One");
  str_deque.addToDeque("And Don't forget My Son");
  str_deque.addToDeque("To include everyone");
  str_deque.addToDeque("I tuck you in");
  str_deque.addToDeque("Warm within");
  str_deque.addToDeque("Keep you free from sin");
  str_deque.addToDeque("Until the sandman he comes");
  str_deque.addToDeque("Sleep with one eye open");
  str_deque.addToDeque("Gripping your pillow tight");
  the_thread.join();
}
```

The error I keep getting is that boost::mutex is noncopyable. The printTheStrings() function takes a reference so I am a little confused as to why this is trying to copy the object.

I have read up a bit on this and one solution I keep reading is to make the boost::mutex a static private member of the object. However, this defeats the purpose of my mutex since I want it to be on an object-by-object basis rather than a class variable.

Is this just bad use of mutexes? Should I just be rethinking this entire application?

EDIT:

I just discovered condition_variable which should serve my purpose a lot better to have the thread wait until there is something actually in the deque before waking up to pop from the deque and print it. All the examples that I see define these mutexes and condition_variable objects at a global scope. This seems very... not object-oriented in my opinion. Even the examples straight from Boost themselves show that it is done in this way. Is this really how other people use these objects?

Comment: Make your class non-copyable then. `delete` copy constructor and assignement operator.

Comment: Don't retell compiler messages, copy and paste them unedited, including their line numbers. Indicate offending lines in tge source.

Comment: Define your own copy constructor where you don't copy the mutex. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.callable_constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that `printToString` takes the `StringQueue` by reference. Your problem is that `boost::thread` take its arguments by value. To force it to take the arguments by reference you will need to modify things to:

```
boost::thread the_thread(printTheStrings, boost::ref(str_deque));
```

As an aside, from C++11 onwards, threads are part of the standard library. You should probably use `std::thread instead`

Comment: I am using an ancient compiler that supports C++11 only in experimental form.